# What is the grammatical name/grammatical funtion of this sentence ending?

Tags: phrases, clauses

> All the students sympathized with their class monitor **whose father was involved in an accident**

What is the grammatical name and the grammatical funtion of the highlighted part of the above?

Comment: As written, it's an integrated relative clause functioning as **modifier** of "class monitor". That's assuming there was more than one class monitor. If, however, there was only one monitor, then the clause should be set apart with a comma and it would then be a supplement, not a modifier.

Comment: Integrated relative clauses are also known as "restrictive" relative clauses because they restrict the identity of the noun phrase they modify.